# Transmit power vs. Transmission power, is there a difference?

Tags: radio, transmitter

I was reading a scientific paper, and the authors sometimes use the term **"transmit power"** and sometimes **"transmission power"**.

Is there a difference in terms of correct English usage?

**Examples:**

> we propose to adjust the transmission power used for...

.

> we propose to use transmit power control in order to...

.

> a higher transmit power of a sender should not be...

Comment: Is the paper written by a native english speaker? Doesn't seem like it. It's a grammatical error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not relate to the design of electronics or similar, rather it belongs in the English Stack Exchange or even a question for EE.SE Chat.

Comment: Clarification of design terms is on topic....

Comment: I agree with @Passerby. Although it is a linguistic question, it is deeply related with EE theory. Whether or not some seemingly incorrect terminology is wrong or not is not likely to be answered correctly by non-technical people. Just an example: the expression "to sort the tree" is something which probably has no sense for someone who doesn't know not only what a tree means in computer science, but what a sort operation on a tree is. I agree with KyranF on the fact that probably it is incorrect if it is written by a non-native speaker, but without seeing more context, it is difficult to say.

Answer (score 4):

The technical usage of these terms in these limited samples/context seems correct. The terms are interchangeable. Their grammatical usage might be a bit odd, but again the context is limited. Seems like someone trying too hard to not use the same words over and over again. A student paper perhaps. Doesn't change the meaning in any case.

Comment: Agreed, they are still the same meaning, just the use of them as a noun or verb ("to transmit" is a verb, "transmission power" is a noun/thing being referred to) seems odd

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

We propose to adjust the transmitted power used for ...

We propose to use power transmission control for ...

A sender's higher power transmission should not be ...

We propose to transmit power to customers located ...

Answer (score 1):

I think context may be mandatory to know the real answer, but it may be that they are using the noun form, "transmission," when referring to the transmission mid-air, and the verb form, "transmit," when referring to the action of transmitting from the point of view of the individual doing the transmitting.

I've also seen situations where there is a difference between your intended values and the actual measured values, especially with antennas.  I don't see enough context to be sure, but if you see knockdown factors appearing in their equations, that may be the distinction they are drawing.